# What game does Extra Credits use in the "Working Conditions" Episode at 6:12

Tags: game-identification

I saw an episode a while back on The Escapist titled "Working Conditions". At about 6:12 there is a screenshot of a game that looks like an RPG. What game is this from?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's [Final Fantasy 14 (Online)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIV). Here's a similar [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FFXIV_battle_interface.png)

Answer (score 5):

It is  [Final Fantasy XIV Online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIV).

[Here](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/screenshots/images/00031/00031905_258.htm) there's the confirmation about the specific screenshot!

Comment: and a similar screenshot on that Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FFXIV_battle_interface.png

Comment: And it's the old version of the game, known as 1.0. It is no longer playable and had been replaced by Final Fantasy XIV: A Realm Reborn. ARR uses a lot of assets from 1.0, but is an entirely different game.